# Unsaved notebook is crashing: is there any way I can save the state of the MathKernel before I kill it?

Tags: kernel

So I'm in the middle of generating some plots and all of the sudden the frontend goes dead and I haven't saved my work. I'm using Mathematica 8 in MacOS X.

The MathKernel process is still running and I'm hoping to be able to extract the In/Out history from it through Terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have coredumped the MathKernel and Mathematica processes in question and duly forced the crashing instances to close. I've re-done all my work, but if anyone knows an easy way to extract inputs from the dump (which is around 1.6GB of binary content) that'd be a great prevention against future crashes :)

Comment: While not directly a solution to your problem, you can instruct a notebook to automatically save as soon as an output is generated. That way if the notebook crashes, you'll at least not lose anything which was already output at that point (unless the notebook happens to crash during saving; in that case it might have the opposite effect; however it didn't happen to me yet, and you might reduce the risk by making copies (unfortunately Mathematica keeps the file open all the time [at least on Linux], which probably makes identifying the time when a save was completed hard).

Answer (score 7):

If there is such a thing, I want to know it for windows and linux based OS'es also.

Battling with the same problem I have found 2 partial solutions:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> before hitting <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> (I think it's <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for Mac's)
2. if you ignored #1 then you might still be able to screenshot the code and reenter it

I have tried **TextRecognize** to restore the text from the image, but it's still a bit off.

[image]

Edit:

If your UI is not locked, you can

- Quit the kernel, Evaluation -> quit kernel -> local (or [add a shortcut for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612))
- Interrupt evaluation

  - on notebook interfaces: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
  - on text-based interfaces: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately, the notebook wasn't responding to my scrolling (or any other action for that matter) and the important bits of code were off-screen...

Answer (score 4):

It just happened to me on the Mac and I managed to save it by doing the following. I opened the Activity Monitor (Applications->Utilities folder) and I found two wolfram kernels running in addition to the Mathematica itself. I killed the kernels by clicking on the "Force a process to quit" button (the little x-button on the upper-left corner). This unfroze mathematica so that I was able to save the file. I'm not sure how this works on Windows/Linux but probably one can do the same with the task manager.

Comment: +1 I can confirm that this works for me as well almost 5 years later under macOS 10.13 and Mathematica 11.2.

Answer (score 3):

How about putting something like this into init.m

```
RunScheduledTask[If[FileExistsQ[
FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "recovermma.please"}]], 
    Save[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "recovermma.txt"}],In]], 300]
```

It's pretty basic - the scheduled task just checks every five minutes for the existence of the trigger file and if it's there it saves the definition of `In` to a text file.

To "recover" the session you just create the trigger file in the appropiate folder and wait up to five minutes.

I am unable to crash the Front End at will so I don't know if it works under those circumstances.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you only save `In`, not also `Out`? BTW, if you are on a Unix-like system (Linux, OS X), you can "crash" the front end from the shell with `kill -9 $PID` where `$PID` has to be replaced by the PID of the front end process (`ps` helps in finding that; if you have only one front end running, `killall` is an easier alternative).

Comment: No particular reason, you could save `Out` as well. It may even be possible to `NotebookSave` the entire active notebook, but I don't know if that works when the front end has crashed.

There might also be a way to directly  poll the front end for responsiveness instead of looking for a trigger file, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm using Windows 7 and killing the front end process takes out the kernel process too.

Comment: You could use this [memory leak](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3682/52) to crash your front-end, and then let us know if it works.

Comment: @rcollyer, I tried it but both the front end and kernel processes exited. They seem to be inextricably linked in Windows.

Comment: It was a thought.