# Is it possible to recover an unsaved notebook after closing it?

Tags: crash, save

I just Ctrl-Alt-Deleted out of Mathematica after I crashed it while running. I had not saved it all day and had done quite a lot of work on it. When I reopen the file, it shows a version with none of the changes I made today -- I guess I never saved it. I don't think I've actually lost work through not saving in fifteen years. Have I managed to do it today, or is there some way to view scripts that ran in the past but weren't saved?

---

**Moderator's note:** I am leaving this question open rather than closing it as a duplicate of one of several linked in the comments because it specifically asks about the possibility of recovering data from a Notebook *that was not saved.*  Please do not post answers explaining how to set up an auto-save system.  Such methods should instead be posted in answer to *other* questions.  –  Mr.Wizard

Comment: I don't think the Mathematica front end has any auto-recovery function.  When the front end crashes, any modifications since the last save of the notebook are lost.  Unfortunately it happened to me more than once ...

Comment: I feared this might be the answer. I'm coming over from Matlab where the script saves on every execution. I suppose this will be a painful reminder to save often in the future. Is there any way to have it automatically save on every execution, to avoid future mishaps?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Yeah, no joy there. Re saving,  depending on the size of your notebook, saving is not instantaneous,  up to agonizingly slow.

Comment: On the bright side, WolframAlpha helped my wife and me choose the name of our son. So I guess Lord Wolfram giveth and Lord Wolfram taketh.

Comment: @Shane o.k. I'll bite. Let's hear it :D

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6435/5478)

Comment: Haha. Nelson. We wanted a name that was uncommon and on a steady decline.

Comment: Save on every execution (may be slow): [NotebookAutoSave](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookAutoSave.html).

Comment: If the Undo stack of your Mathematica (v10) stack gets too big it's possible that it stores undo information on disk. This behavior depends on various settings and is largely undocumented and perhaps even not fully implemented yet. You may have such a temporary file somewhere that might be decodable. But I wouldn't  give you much chance.

Comment: Related: [(4037)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4037/121), [(6435)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6435/121), [(8761)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8761/121), [(18380)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18380/121), [(26740)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26740/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've deleted my answer as requested and posted to one of the possible duplicates. 26740 seems the most appropriate but if you feel it is better suited to one of the other questions feel free to move it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I realized that it is a duplicate now after I saw your comments. I don't know if I should delete my answer or not.

Comment: @Algohi You do not need to delete your answer.  I was encouraging Mike (and everyone) to "move" answers from duplicates to the original by deleting and reposting, to both give them better exposure for the future and improve site organization.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question is not a duplicate of the questions you have listed. My question was regarding recovering the code following a lockup (whether it was possible), not on avoiding losses through saving. It turns out it is not possible -- though Sjoerd hinted at one long shot. I suppose the best answer to the question then is just "No - it's gone". Granted, I'm sure an answer to that effect exists in one of the questions you cite. That said, none of those will appear pertinent to people like me searching for recovery tips after a crash. Do you disagree?

Comment: @Shane I agree with you. Confusion arises because the answer you Accepted does not answer the question you asked. A more closely related question is (4037) added to my comment above.  If we leave this question Open it would make far more sense *not* to Accept an answer that has little to do with it, in my opinion.  This question needs to be answered with one of: (1) Proof that recovery is possible; (2) An explanation that it is not possible; (3) New functionality that makes it possible. (e.g. [(52374)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52374/121)).  Do *you* disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Haha - I agree. I suppose upon finding out that no pleasing answer is possible (or at least not likely), it's tempting to accept answers that, while not directly answering the question, avoid the question from being an issue in the future. In terms of site organization, though, I agree it's best to avoid that. Go ahead and close the question if you think it best - I trust your judgment as moderator.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A further note - keep in mind (and I'm not saying you're not conscious of this) that it's easy to find information on SE when you already know where it is, or at least have familiarity with the particular community to create good searches. I'm a little more active in Math.SE (though not all that much), and I'm sometimes baffled by how new users miss pre-existing questions/answers. More often than not, though, they have actually searched quite a bit and just couldn't formulate the correct search to reveal what they were looking for. The same happened to me here.

Comment: @Shane I am well aware that search is difficult; it is why I spend as much of my time as I do hunting for related questions and linking them as I did above.  If you un-Accept the answer I shall leave this question open, otherwise I shall close it as it brings nothing unique.  I would prefer you to choose the former as some day I hope to see a crash recovery feature.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Will do. I appreciate your assistance - I learned a fair bit about avoiding code loss looking through the linked questions.

Answer (score 11):

In fact, it is possible to tell Mathematica that "the notebook should automatically be saved after each piece of output generated by evaluation in it"; see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookAutoSave.html).  Place

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, NotebookAutoSave -> True]
NotebookSave[]
```

at the beginning of a new notebook.  When this code is executed, it asks the user where to save the notebook.  Once this information is provided, the notebook is saved.  More importantly, it is saved each time a cell is executed to produce an `Out` line.

Thereafter, when the notebook is closed, subsequently reopened, and an `Out` line produced, the notebook is saved.  The downside, of course, is that saving the notebook repeatedly takes time.  Moreover, all executed changes, both the good and the bad, are saved.

Note that `NotebookAutoSave -> True` also can be set using `OptionsInspector`.  With "Show options values" set to "Selected Notebook", type `NotebookAutoSave` into "Lookup:", and it will appear under "NotebookOptions/File Options

Update: Just saw closely related answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/is-there-a-notebook-autosave-frequency-configuration).

Answer (score 7):

If your notebook is hung/non-responsive, and you haven't saved changes, don't give up!  You can try to kill the kernel processes without killing Mathematica and revive it.

I just did this on MacOS using the Activity Monitor program.  I was evaluating my notebook, and it got stuck and stopped responding.  I saw WSMKernelX and WolframKernel processes, selected one, selected the x button to quit, then selected the other one and quit it.  I didn't have to do a force quit (for both, at least).  The Mathematica process came back alive, and I saved it!

Comment: Great advice on killing kernels. I've had to do that many times, and many times dread the time it will take to reload data. But DumpSave helps with that issue. Still... Mathematica crashes A LOT. I know several guaranteed ways to crash the front end and at least 2 ways to get the kernel to die when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

You can add at the beginning or at the end of your notebook this command:

```
NotebookSave[]
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that's my best bet.

Comment: An additional note, if you want to save to a backup file on each execution, this can be done with NotebookSave[], but then it puts you into working in the backup file. If you want to save to a backup file on each execution but stay in your main file, this works for me (though there's likely a more elegant solution out there): Export[NotebookFileName[] <> ".backup.nb", EvaluationNotebook[]];