# Recover a never-saved notebook?

Tags: notebooks, crash

I was working on a notebook when my computer crashed. I hadn't saved it at any point before the crash. Is there any way to  recover the content of that notebook?

(Please note that I'm not trying to autosave a notebook in the future. I'm just trying to recover this one!)

Comment: You could ask Wolfram support, but I wouldn’t hold my breath...

Comment: See [Is it possible to recover an unsaved notebook after closing it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74205/27951), but no very good news there either I’m afraid.

Comment: @MarcoB Would there a way to reap the history that are stored in `In` and `Out` if only the notebook crashed, but not the kernel?

Comment: @QuantumDot If the FE crashes, and thus the MathLink connection to the kernel breaks, then the kernel quits immediately.

Comment: @lastminute I believe that there is no way to recover it. I do not think that there are automatic periodic backups like with MS Word.