# Memory leak in FE?

Tags: front-end, performance-tuning, dynamic, bugs, memory

A very abridged example of what was originally a major leak

```
{Animator[Dynamic@α, RefreshRate -> 120],
 Dynamic[arrows = (α; Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0., 1} + 0.001 RandomReal[2, 2]}]);],
 Dynamic[Graphics[arrows, ImageSize -> Tiny]
  ]}
```

I'm running Windows 7, x64, Mathematica 8.0.4. The Mathematica.exe process slowly (in this example) grows in memory usage and nothing I tried other than close and reopen Mathematica, seems to help.

Can you reproduce the problem? Is it known? What exactly is causing it? Any way to handle it?

I haven't got much experience in interfaces, but I had done a satisfactory one only to realise after a while it was using up 1.5GB of RAM

Comment: How fast is the memory leaking on your machine for this example? I see something like 0.5 MB increase in memory/10 mins of running.

Comment: Ok, it gets faster at some point. Now it's at 250 MB after 1 hr. 8.04 on MacOSX.

Comment: Confirmed on version 7 under Windows 7.   It is significantly worse with `Animator[Dynamic@α, RefreshRate -> 120]`

Comment: Confirmed here too. Windows7-64, MMA 8.04. There's indeed a speed-up after some time. I'd say I lose about 1 MB/s (using Mr.Wizard's setting).

Comment: This looks like a multi-platform/multi-version bug indeed. Could you report this to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: I haven't had time yet to test more and answer, but I see that it's a shared concern. Actually I had done 2 interfaces and both had the issue, so my style clearly is buggy. I just mailed support@wolfram. Let's see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reported, and forwarded to the developers. It is still there in v9

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it's the `Graphics[arrows]` part. This:

```
{Animator[Dynamic@\[Alpha], RefreshRate -> 120], 
 Dynamic[arrows = (\[Alpha]; 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0., 1} + 0.001 RandomReal[2, 2]}]);], 
 Dynamic[Graphics[arrows];]}
```

Does not produce a memory leak for me: MMA 8.0.0 on Win7-64. Is it possible it is a history / `Out[]` type problem?

Comment: I still get a memory leak with this but it's a slow one.  I suppose it's related to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3682/121) where each unique object created is cached somehow.

Comment: I even get a slow leak with `{Animator[Dynamic@\[Alpha], RefreshRate -> 120], 
 Dynamic[arrows = (\[Alpha];
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0., 1}}]);], Dynamic[Null]}` so there is perhaps a separate leak even without unique objects.