# Memory Leak while running Animate/Manipulate/Export

Tags: memory

While looking into building a simulation for an ant colony, I started encountering some memory leakage issues.

```
 ymax = 1000; xmax = 1000;
 nest = {500, 500};
 maxAnts = 30;
 steps = 200;
 maxSpeed = 20;
 maxAngle = π/6;

 orientation = 
   RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 2 π}], maxAnts];
ant = Table[
   agent[∞, nest, orientation[[i]], #] & /@ Range[i], {i, 
    maxAnts}];

update[agent[symbol_, location_, direction_, t_]] := 
Module[{dir, speed, loc}, 
  dir = First@
    RandomVariate[
     UniformDistribution[{direction - maxAngle, 
       direction + maxAngle}], 1]; 
  speed = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{1, maxSpeed}], 1];
  loc = Flatten[location + Round[{speed*Cos[dir], speed*Sin[dir]}]];
  loc = Min[#] & /@ Transpose[{loc, {xmax, ymax}}];
  loc = Max[#] & /@ Transpose[{loc, {0, 0}}];
  agent[symbol, loc, dir, t + 1]]

display[agent[symbol_, location_, direction_, t_]] := 
Text[Rotate[symbol, direction], location]
display[list_] := Module[{lst = display[#] & /@ list}, Graphics[lst]]

history = 
  Join[ant[[#]], 
     NestList[update, Last@ant[[#]], steps - Length[ant[[#]]]]] & /@ 
   Range[maxAnts];

Animate[Show[Graphics[display[history[[All, i]]]], 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[nest]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, {0, ymax}}], {i, 1, steps, 1}]
```

[image: Animation]

The issue I have is that Mathematica seems to have a memory leak, as the Animate, or manipulate, or exporting to gif runs, the amount of memory allocated to Mathematica keeps growing until it just stops working. Below is a gif in which I turn the animation on and off to show that the memory keeps growing as Animate (or Manipulate) runs. A bummer because this limits the number of ants and steps to use.

[image: Memory Leakage]

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/memory-leak-in-fe

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. Placed a support ticket with Wolfram Research.