# Why does this line increase the consumed memory?

Tags: programming, image-processing, memory, filtering, performance-tuning

Probably this is a simple question, however I really don't understand this behavior in *Mathematica*. It particularly leads to a memory leak in a huge program I have to do processing of 3D images. I broke it down which took me quite a time and had to figure out that the problem occured in a simple function that includes a `GaussianFilter` in `Block`. The following simple code increases the memory each time I execute it and I can't figure out how to stop this:

```
image = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];

oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
GaussianFilter[image, 1];
N[(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000]
```

> 58.6569

Meaning that the consumed RAM increases by about 58 MB when the filter is applied even though nothing is returned. I checked for the data type that is produced by the `GaussianFilter`. The data type changes from `Byte` to `Real32`. I know that *Mathematica* stores output internally but nothing is returned. Especially, I don't understand why the memory is never freed even if I put the stuff into scoping structures like `Block`. By the way, setting `$HistoryLength` to 0 doesn't help either.

```
ImageType@image
ImageType@GaussianFilter[image, 1]
```

> Byte
>
> Real32

```
fun[image_] := Block[
   {},
   GaussianFilter[image, 1];
   ];

oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
fun[image];
N[(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000]
```

> 58.6571

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
fun[image];
N[(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000]
```

> 58.6571

The same problem also occurs when using `Map`:

```
oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
$HistoryLength = 0;
Map[GaussianFilter[img3d, 1] &, Range[1, 10]];
oldMem/1000/1000 // N
MemoryInUse[]/1000/1000 // N
(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000 // N
```

> 28.9377
>
> 620.817
>
> 591.878

Without saving anything into a variable, the memory has increased by 590 MB. Besides, setting `$HistoryLength` to zero shows no effect. I also tried to Clear `In` and `Out`, again with no effect.

```
Unprotect[In, Out]
Clear[In, Out]
```

**System specifictation**

- OS: Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1 (64-bit)
- Processor: Intel    Xeon CPU E5630 @ 2.53 GHz (2 Processors)
- Installed memory: 96 GB
- *Mathematica* 10.0.1

Comment: Wow, quite a bit of RAM available there ;-)  Does changing `$HistoryLength=0` show any effect?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. No doesn't have any effect. I will add it directly. It seems that the filter just soaks up my memory ;)

Comment: quite a bit of RAM available, yes. But at some point even 96 GB are gone ... ;)

Comment: Does this continue indeterminately, or is there a cap after which use of memory doesn't raise any more? Nothing really guarantees that garbage collectors return conceptually vacant memory right away, and there are many use cases where this makes sense (especially if the collection is not based on reference counting). It may be a bug, but it may also be an internal implementation detail of the collector, for instance considering garbage collection only every N object allocations.

Comment: I applied it several times using Map and Table and the memory consumption raises in each iteration. If i would run it long enough it would certainly kill my computer (which it did already in the real program I use this line). So it never stops or returns the memory...

Comment: Is this version-dependent? I [recently asked a question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65055/is-there-a-way-to-control-v10s-undo-length) about a memory growth problem that turned out to occur because of V10's undo feature. However, in this case I'm not sure it's applicable because there is no output in your code.

Comment: Could be an interesting idea, thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have version 9 installed to try that with another version than 10. I tried the code using UndoOptions but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Memory is still leaking...

Comment: You may also try `Share[]`

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of the function Share before. I added it but it doesn't seem to have an effect... unfortunately...

Comment: Have you asked WRI?

Comment: Not yet. I still think that I might do something wrong.

Comment: I'd also suggest contacting support and/or posting on community.wolfram.com.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on v9 (Windows 7 64 bit).  I don't have access to v10; however the problem does appear on WPC.

Comment: I ran the following sequence with versions 9.0.1 and 10.0.1:`MemoryInUse[]` `image = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"]` `MemoryInUse[]` `GaussianFilter[image, 1];` `MemoryInUse[]`. For version 10, the three memory numbers were 24600632, 35537848, 124676320. Thus, my computer consumed even more memory than the result given by @g3kk0. Next, I save the file and ran it with version 9, obtaining 26650296, 39502464, 97985304.  Finally, I recreated the file and ran it on version 9, obtaining 25525112, 45144176, 104086784.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some debugging ideas and a possible workaround.  Note that for v10, I am using the Wolfram Programming Cloud, which as far as I can tell, is reproducing your results.

### Version specific specific problem

Using this code:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
i = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];
oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
GaussianFilter[i, 5];
N[(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000]
```

A fresh WPC session returns 62.8 and a fresh v9 (Windows 7, 64-bit) returns 2.11.  Subsequent executions of the same cell in WPC always to 62.8 until such point that I have reached the maximum memory allocated to my plan.  On v9, however, four executions of the same cell results in -0.000952 being returned.

### Independent of filter

Note that the same problem occurs when `GaussianFilter` is replaced with `LaplacianFilter`, `LaplacianGaussianFilter`, but **not** `GradientFilter`.  For the latter, I obtain similar values for the memory difference on the WPC and v9.  For the Laplacian and Gaussian filters, memory differences are on the order of 60 MB.

### Possible workaround

The problem appears to lie in how the filters are using 3D image files.  If we extract ImageData, the problem seems to be mitigated:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
i = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];
oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
Image3D@GaussianFilter[ImageData@i, 5];
N[(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000]
```

The output of the above code block is 1.5 on the WPC and 2.1 on v9.  Both platforms return a negative value after 4 executions of the same cell.

It appears that converting the image to data prior to filtering *may* be a suitable workaround.

```
i2 = GaussianFilter[i, 5]
i3 = Image3D[GaussianFilter[ImageData@i, 5]]
```

`i2===i3` returns false; however `ImageDifference[i2,i3]` returns:

[image]

### A bit of spelunking

@SimonWoods traced the problem to `` Image`FilteringDump`image3DConvolve `` and came to a similar conclusion with respect to a possible workaround.  He graciously allowed me to copy his answer into this one for completeness.

Using [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) and [Spelunk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/862) I tracked the evaluation of your `GaussianFilter` through to `` Image`FilteringDump`image3DConvolve ``. The memory leak occurs somewhere inside that function, though I was unable to pin it down any further. I couldn't find any sign of leaked temporary symbols in the `Image` context, so I guess the memory leak is somewhere inside the kernel code.

For a workaround you can apply the filter to the image data directly, which will use `ListConvolve` internally rather than `` Image`FilteringDump`image3DConvolve ``:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
image = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];

oldMem = MemoryInUse[];
Image3D @ GaussianFilter[ImageData @ image, 1];
N[(MemoryInUse[] - oldMem)/1000/1000]

(* 0.000984 *)
```

Comment: I couldn't think of this straightforward solution, thanks :) However, I will report this memory leak as a bug to Wolfram support.